# How to bind keys to only one of the notebook tab

Tags: python, tkinter

I wanted to bind 'Enter' key to only one of the tab, here's the sample code

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk


def hello(event):
    print('hello')


window = Tk()
window.geometry('500x500')
tab_control = ttk.Notebook(window)
tab_1 = ttk.Frame(tab_control)
tab_2 = ttk.Frame(tab_control)
tab_control.add(tab_1, text='Tab 1')
tab_control.add(tab_2, text='Tab 2')
tab_control.pack(expand=1, fill='both')

window.bind('<Return>', hello)

window.mainloop()
```

`window.bind()` will allow the user to run `hello()` function in both tabs. But I only wish to bind it to `tab_1`.

I tried `tab_1.bind('<Return>', hello)` but there's no response at all in both tab.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `<<NotebookTabChanged>>` event to get the active tab,then bind event for your app:

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

def hello(event=None):
    print("hello")

def e(event=None):
    if tab_control.index(tab_control.select()) == 0: # bind event for the first tab.
        window.bind("<Return>", hello)
    else:
        window.unbind("<Return>")


window = Tk()
window.geometry('500x500')
tab_control = ttk.Notebook(window)

tab_1 = ttk.Frame(tab_control)
tab_2 = ttk.Frame(tab_control)
tab_control.add(tab_1, text='Tab 1')
tab_control.add(tab_2, text='Tab 2')
tab_control.pack(expand=1, fill='both')

window.bind('<<NotebookTabChanged>>', e)

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `select()` method of `Notebook` in tkinter. Here's an example:

Suppose you have a notebook with 2 frames in it. And no matter what happens, when you press the `Return` key in your keyboard, the focus should be one the first frame then use this:

```
name_of_notebook.select(0)
```

Here 0 is like the index number as it starts at zero.

Note: When setting keybinds, make sure to bind them right to the widget in which a change should happen